# strictNullChecks causes error: hasOwnProperty does not exist for generic types

Tags: typescript

My code works well without --strictNullChecks.

When enabling --strictNullChecks, the following error occurs:

Property 'hasOwnProperty' does not exist on type 'T1'.
Property 'hasOwnProperty' does not exist on type 'T2'.

```js
function extend<T1, T2>(arg1: T1, arg2: T2): T1 & T2 {
    const result: Partial<T1 & T2> = {};
    for (const prop in arg1) {
        if (arg1.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { // error when using --strictNullChecks
            (result as T1)[prop] = arg1[prop];
        }
    }
    for (const prop in arg2) {
        if (arg2.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { // error when using --strictNullChecks
            (result as T2)[prop] = arg2[prop];
        }
    }
    return result as T1 & T2;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Since they're unbounded generics, T1 or T2 could be `null` or `undefined`, neither of which has `hasOwnProperty`.

You'll need to mark them as extending object:

```
function extend<T1 extends object, T2 extends object>(arg1: T1, arg2: T2): T1 & T2 {
// ---------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    const result: Partial<T1 & T2> = {};
    for (const prop in arg1) {
        if (arg1.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { // error when using --strictNullChecks
            (result as T1)[prop] = arg1[prop];
        }
    }
    for (const prop in arg2) {
        if (arg2.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { // error when using --strictNullChecks
            (result as T2)[prop] = arg2[prop];
        }
    }
    return result as T1 & T2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I still don't understand one thing: why does the error occur only when enabling strictNullChecks? Without strictNullChecks T1 and T2 can also be null.

Comment: @Harry - Truthfully, I don't know. :-) I'm a bit surprised that it doesn't have the error without it (I've verified it, I'm just surprised by it). It could relate to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#in-strictnullchecks-an-unconstrained-type-parameter-is-no-longer-assignable-to-object).

Comment: This solved an issue for me trying to update `T` from `Partial<T>`

Answer (score 1):

You can find more on the subject [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes), but basically Typescript doesn't know that your generic type is an Object.

It is assuming, and rightfully so, that it could be anything, including a string, number or even null. So it wouldn't make any sense to allow you to call `hasOwnProperty` on those.

You need to specify your generic types a bit more than that.

```
function extend<T1 extends object, T2 extends object>(arg1: T1, arg2: T2): T1 & T2;
```

Comment: Strings and numbers have hasOwnProperty method, as any primitive value, due to autoboxing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive#autoboxing_primitive_wrapper_objects_in_javascript

Comment: That's an implicit JavaScript wrapper calling Number or String on your value before calling the method. Typescript doesn't care about that. To quote your doc "In JavaScript, a primitive (primitive value, primitive data type) is data that is not an object and has no methods or properties." so it would be incorrect to call hasOwnProperty on a primitive string type.

Answer (score -1):

`.hasOwnProperty` is the property of an Object, which the generic doesn't know. You can use `T1 extends {}` to inherit those types

```
function extend<T1 extends {}, T2 extends {}>(arg1: T1, arg2: T2): T1 & T2 {
    const result: Partial<T1 & T2> = {};
    for (const prop in arg1) {
        if (arg1.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { // error when using --strictNullChecks
            (result as T1)[prop] = arg1[prop];
        }
    }
    for (const prop in arg2) {
        if (arg2.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { // error when using --strictNullChecks
            (result as T2)[prop] = arg2[prop];
        }
    }
    return result as T1 & T2;
}
```